# I want to decode this JSON Response

Tags: json, swift

I am trying to decode the response from JSON to my object upload photo but I am facing the error. Invalid conversion from throwing function of type `(_) throws -> ()` to non-throwing function type `(DefaultDataResponse) -> Void`

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {

    let image = self.photo
    let uploaded_file = (image?.jpegData(compressionQuality: 0.2)!)!
    let url = URLs.profileImage

    Alamofire.upload(multipartFormData: { multipartFormData in
        multipartFormData.append(uploaded_file, withName: "uploaded_file",fileName: "uploaded_file", mimeType: "image/jpg") 
    }, to: url)
    { (result) in
        switch result {
        case .success(let upload, _, _):

            upload.uploadProgress(closure: { (progress) in
                print("Upload Progress: \(progress.fractionCompleted)")
            })

            upload.response { response in
                print(response.result.value!)
                let data = response.data

                print(JSON(response.data))
                let jsonDecoder = JSONDecoder()
                let res = try jsonDecoder.decode(uploadPhoto.self, from: data ) as uploadPhoto
            }

        case .failure(let encodingError):
            print(encodingError)
        }
    }
}
```

I would like to decode the response. so I can get the values from JSON.

JSON response:

```
{
    "code": 200,
    "message": "Image Uploaded Successfully",
    "image_link": "uploads\/profile\/1562737080_icons8-key-50 (1).png"
}
```

Comment: The actual reason of the error is the missing `do catch` block around the `decode` line. And the bridge cast to the same type `as uploadPhoto` is nonsense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried using respone.result.value?

```
if let resultDict = response.result.value as? [String: Any] {
    let message = resultDict ["message"]
    //...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If the **JSON** response has the format,

```
{
    "code": 200,
    "message": "Image Uploaded Successfully",
    "image_link": "uploads/profile/1562737080_icons8-key-50 (1).png"
}
```

**Model** for parsing the above JSON will be like,

```
struct UploadPhoto: Codable {
    let code: Int
    let message: String
    let imageLink: String
}
```

**Parse** it using:

```
do {
    let decoder = JSONDecoder()
    decoder.keyDecodingStrategy = .convertFromSnakeCase
    let response = try decoder.decode(UploadPhoto.self, from: data)
    print(response)
} catch {
    print(error)
}
```

Comment: Cannot invoke 'decode' with an argument list of type '(() -> (), from: Data)'

Comment: Check the type of `data` that you're using?

Comment: It is of Data type

Comment: @SumyiaYaseen Consider the crucial `do catch` block in the answer.

Comment: I did but no improvement.